# How to find if iPhone is unlocked for worldwide GSM use

Tags: iphone, unlock

I am new here. I am looking for an iPhone online but, want to know if a particular phone would work with GSM carriers outside US. Is there a proper way to find that? Specially the iPhones unlocked from US carriers.

Answer (score 1):

If the Iphone is unlocked just trying with a difference SIM card from another carrier should be work without any problem.

Comment: That seems like quite the hassle if you don't already have another SIM card.